# how to minify JavaScript file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Do you know of a plugin for Visual Studio Code that will minify a JS file?  I'd like to minify a file as soon as it is saved.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of now, there are some available extensions: for example [Minify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.minify) or [JS & CSS Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=olback.es6-css-minify)

*Note:* You can find extensions on the *[VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=minify&target=VSCode&sortBy=Relevance)*.

Or directly from VS Code by searching from the *Extensions* pane, on the left side (Ctrl + Shift + X).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171451/discussion-between-samirg-and-supersharp).

Comment: This extension is no longer updated. Several feature requests and pull requests out there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Web Essentials 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee6e6d8c-c837-41fb-886a-6b50ae2d06a2), it does this and a lot more.

Comment: I believe Web Essentials 2015 is for Visual Studio 2015, not for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You are correct; sorry. I have not used Visual Studio Code. Another option would be to use "grunt" or "gulp" with a watcher... but that's not really an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Visual Studio Code Minify Plugins on Google. There are plenty. For example, [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn6PXK4arOAhXHLSYKHcm6Dm0QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com%2F9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40&usg=AFQjCNFGTdw_OI9lBdl-EHb-b56IcQdM-A&sig2=k4KxSv6m1uC4dozC0gB9qg), and [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn6PXK4arOAhXHLSYKHcm6Dm0QFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com%2F5469b7e2-90d7-4f54-b299-ae47e26323e6&usg=AFQjCNHCt3iMHAbaOetlEXQWLET00Nxegg&sig2=V6bUl7wN1Gbmoix_SH86gQ).

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Are these for Visual Studio Code?  They seem to be for Visual Studio 2015 or 2010, 2012